# Is it possible to compute Lie bialgebra structures with SageMath?

Tags: computer-algebra, sage, bialgebras

Is it possible to use SageMath (or some Linux open source program) to compute the bialgebra structures on a given finite dimensional Lie algebra? I wonder if such program can compute all the cobrackets and write down all the quadratic equations coming from the Jacobi identity ; similar to the variety of Lie algebra structures on a given finite dimensional vector space.